# pandas: Pandas cannot to reset index because name exist

Tags: python, pandas

Please im gotting error in my code **ValueError: cannot insert id, already exists**

```
import datetime
df.groupby(['id']).resample('W-Mon', on='date').sum().reset_index()
df = df.groupby('id').resample('W', on='date').sum().reset_index()
df['date'] = df.date - pd.Timedelta('6D')
```

**update**

```
import datetime
df.groupby(['id2']).resample('W-Mon', on='date').sum().reset_index()
df = df.groupby('id2').resample('W', on='date').sum().reset_index()
df['date'] = df.date - pd.Timedelta('6D')
```

**dict()**

```
{'id2': {1286151: Decimal('2221'),
1257419: Decimal('2222'),
5678454: Decimal('2223'),
2067246: Decimal('2224'),}

'date': {1286151: datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),
1257419: datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),
5678454: datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),
2067246: datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),}

'rev': {1286151: Decimal('173.909'),
1257419: Decimal('386.705'),
5678454: Decimal('541.427'),
2067246: Decimal('579.989'),}
```

Comment: 'id' is already a column. So when you do ```reset_index()```, a new 'id' column is trying to come into place (which was your index), but it can't, as there is already a column called 'id' in that dataframe. You can rename your current 'id' column to something else, and then it should work.

Comment: same error when tried to rename the column id with id2. See my update please

Comment: can you provide a sample of your dataset please? If you could do ```df.to_dict()``` and paste that in the question, we might be able to help. There's a limit on the help that can be offered without access to the input data :)

Comment: @direction Try reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: samething @Jayvee

Comment: @sophocles i updated my original post, please have a look

Comment: I think you did ```dict(df)```, and pasted it. Please do ```df.to_dict()```, and paste it

Comment: no no i did df.to_dict()

Answer (score 2):

This was also answered in comments by @Jayvee

`reset_index()` has one argument which is of help in your case

your index is also one of columns of dataframe so when you reindex, should put `drop=True` in `reset_index()` so that your problem would be solved

```
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```